# Is there a way to preview RAW photos on an Android tablet from a PC over a network?

Tags: photos, remote-control

Is there a way to share RAW (Canon) photos over a network and preview them on an android tablet (Kindle Fire)?

I want to be able to quickly preview new photos without having to convert them to JPEG and copy to the tablet.

One potential possibility I can think of is exposing the photos as an RSS feed and using an android app like Just Pictures to consume the feed, but I don't know of a way to create the feed in Adobe Bridge or Lightroom.

Answer (score 1):

There are Apps which allows you to connect to your PC and control it with your Android device. These are generally referred as Remote Desktop Applications.

For Android, there are many remote desktop apps, one that I have tried is called Splashtop. I know LogMeIn, which is quite famous among remote desktop softwares, also has Android/iOS version available.

However these Apps are usually not free.

While these Apps can do exactly what you want, it can also do much more than just viewing RAW photos, basically it enables you to use your Android device as your PC's LCD monitor, so you can run any programs, open any files etc. Therefore these Apps tend not to be cheap.

Comment: Interesting approach.  I doubt it would be an android friendly experience though. E.g. a way to show the photos in full screen mode and navigate by swiping .

Answer (score 0):

you should check RawVision:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.caketuzz.RawVision

It will allow you to check your photos without converting to JPEG, but there is no way you will check pohtos without sending them to the tab first. Now there are several means to have the photos on the tab, it mainly depends on the tab itself and its connectivity.

Usually, you will want to share the photos after checking them, rather than the other way. So that's what the app will allow you.

Comment: Thanks! This may be an option if I find a way to mount an SMB share no Kindle Fire.